# Is there a way to have metadata of values at compile time?

Tags: clojure

I wrote a specialized function construct, which under the hood is really just a Clojure function. So basically I have a function that makes (similar to `fn`) and a function that calls my specialized functions (similar to CL's `funcall`).

My constructor assigns metadata (at compile-time) so I could distinguish between "my" functions and other/normal Clojure functions.

What I want to do is to make a macro that lets users write code as if my functions were normal functions. It would do so by walking over the code, and in functions calls, when the callee is a specialized function, it would change the call so it would use my caller (and also inject some extra information). For example:

```
(defmacro my-fn [args-vector & body] ...)
(defmacro my-funcall [myfn & args] ...)
(defmacro with-my-fns [& body] ...)

(with-my-fns
  123
  (first [1 2 3])
  ((my-fn [x y] (+ x y))) 10 20)
; should yield:
(do
  123
  (first [1 2 3])
  (my-funcall (my-fn [x y] (+ x y)) 10 20))
```

I run into problems in lexical environments. For example:

```
(with-my-fns
  (let [myf (my-fn [x y] (+ x y))]
    (myf))
```

In this case, when the macro I want to write (i.e. `with-my-fns`) encounters `(myf)`, it sees `myf` as a symbol, and I don't have access to the metadata. It's also not a Var so I can't `resolve` it.

I care to know because otherwise I'll have to put checks on almost every single function call at runtime. Note that I don't really care if my metadata on the values are actual Clojure metadata; if it's possible with the type-system and whatnot it's just as good.

P.S. I initially wanted to just ask about lexical environments, but maybe there are more pitfalls I should be aware of where my approach would fail? (or maybe even the above is actually an XY problem? I'd welcome suggestions).

Comment: As far as I understood, you are attaching metadata to runtime object (function). Obviously, it is not possible to access metadata of runtime object at compile time (without `eval`uating it)

Comment: @OlegTheCat Yeah, that's the problem (although iirc actual Clojure metadata did work except when bound in a lexical environment). Is there no way to have this data available at compile time (through metadata or otherwise)?

Comment: why don't you put all the magic inside the myfun macro? Why can't you add all the checks there?

Comment: @murphy The magic is injecting data that's available at the time of the call to a hidden parameter.

Comment: Did you have a look at implicit `&env` variable? Will it help? doc: http://clojure.org/reference/macros#_special_variables, usage: http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-and.html

Comment: @OlegTheCat Yeah, I think so! I'll have to try this but I think I can define my function as a record and then follow the `LocalBinding` where the function chain `.init .fexpr .var` leads to `->MyFn`. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1):

As @OlegTheCat already pointed out in the comment section, the idea to use meta-data does not work.

However I might have a solution you can live with:

```
(ns cl-myfn.core)

(defprotocol MyCallable
  (call [this magic args]))


(extend-protocol MyCallable
  ;; a clojure function implements IFn
  ;; we use this knowledge to simply call it
  ;; and ignore the magic
  clojure.lang.IFn
  (call [this _magic args]
    (apply this args)))

(deftype MyFun [myFun]
  MyCallable
  ;; this is our magic type
  ;; for now it only adds the magic as first argument
  ;; you may add all the checks here
  (call [this magic args]
    (apply (.myFun this) magic args)))

;;turn this into a macro if you want more syntactic sugar
(defn make-myfun [fun]
  (MyFun. fun))

(defmacro with-myfuns [magic & funs]
  `(do ~@(map (fn [f#]
                ;; if f# is a sequence it is treated as a function call                
                (if (seq? f#)
                  (let [[fun# & args#] f#]
                    `(call ~fun# ~magic [~@args#]))

                  ;; if f# is nonsequential it is left alone
                  f#))
                funs)))


(let [my-prn (make-myfun prn)]
  (with-myfuns :a-kind-of-magic
    123 
    [1 2 3]
    (prn :hello) 
    (my-prn 123)))


;; for your convenience: the macro-expansion 

(let [my-prn (make-myfun prn)]
  (prn (macroexpand-1 '(with-myfuns :a-kind-of-magic
                         123
                         [1 2 3]
                         (prn :hello) 
                         (my-prn 123)))))
```

the output:

```
:hello
:a-kind-of-magic 123
(do 123 [1 2 3] (cl-myfn.core/call prn :a-kind-of-magic [:hello]) (cl-myfn.core/call my-prn :a-kind-of-magic [123]))
```